# Separate app.use() vs chained app.use().use()... in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I've noticed that all of the examples use...

```js
app.use(express.static("./app/public"))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(routeOne)
app.use(routeTwo)
```

Is anything wrong with this?

```js
app
    .use(express.static("./app/public"))

    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    .use(bodyParser.json())

    .use(routeOne)
    .use(routeTwo)
```

It works as expected, just not sure about some unexpected behavior.

Comment: It is fine and it is called [Method Chaining](https://schier.co/blog/method-chaining-in-javascript). Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59668584/2436655

Comment: Don't forget, the order of your `use()` calls matters, whether or not you chain them.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, my Google Fu failed me.